# How to dismiss the numeric keyboard after ten digits?

Tags: ios

I have a scene within a storyboard, and within that scene there lies a textfield.

This textfield is desinged to hold a telephone number, so I want the numpad to dismiss / disappear after 10 digits have been inputted.

I saw a very similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203647/uitextfield-dismiss-keyboard-when-two-digits-have-been-entered) but when I tried putting the code in my ViewController.m file the numpad did not disappear.  If anyone can help shed some light on my situation I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh, that solution **should** work.  one of these:

- Check out your target UITextField has a delegate, and it equals `self`
- Use debugger to see if `-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` ever called.

Comment: When I drag the delegate wire under "Outlets" from the Utilities pane to the textfield in the storyboard view it will not establish a connection.  It will allow me to drag the wire labeled delegate (when I have the textfield selected) to other objects in the scene, but not itself.