# Dismiss keyboard after a user entered 11 digit

Tags: ios, swift, dismiss

I've been looking for a solution in the site to dismiss keyboard after a user entered 11 digits. I found a [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203647/uitextfield-dismiss-keyboard-when-two-digits-have-been-entered) here, but it is an Objective-c and I'm looking for a swift code, can anybody help?

Comment: First of all, show us what you tried ?

Comment: Converting from Objective-C is a really important, real world skill - so much code is still/only available in ObjC, worth taking the time to try and convert it

Comment: You forgot to try by your self or put it here

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't want to convert it !! I am looking for the swift one!

Comment: @Am1rFT :/ Then I recommend that you keep looking - it's undoubtful that anyone is going to write one for you - that's not what SO is for - no offence

Comment: I have an If statement : if National_ID.text?.count == 11{ ... }
 like this . when a button is pressed ,and this if statement return true  , then app will continue , but it won't prevent the user not to enter more than 11 digits !

Comment: share you objc code which you wants to convert.

Comment: @ShamimHossain it is available in the question

Comment: use this @IBAction func tfEdiotingChange(_ sender: UITextField) {
        print("tfEdiotingChange...\(String(describing: sender.text))")
        if sender.text?.count == 11 {
            sender.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    } this IBAction is the editingchanged outlet of the text field.

Comment: textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanged), for: . editingChanged)


func textChanged() { 

let count: Int = textField.text?.count ?? 0
    if count >= 11 {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it works

```
  func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

   // YOU SHOULD FIRST CHECK FOR THE BACKSPACE. IF BACKSPACE IS PRESSED ALLOW IT

    if string == "" {
        return true
    }

    if let characterCount = textField.text?.count {
        // CHECK FOR CHARACTER COUNT IN TEXT FIELD
        if characterCount >= 11 {
            // RESIGN FIRST RERSPONDER TO HIDE KEYBOARD
            return textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

**EDIT**

1) You should set the IBOutlet to your textField

2) Set delegate to self, on your textField.

3) YourViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate { }

4) Implement the delegate method as in above. check for the backspace and allow if user enters backspace to remove characters from textField.

Comment: why should we need "      shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String  "

Comment: this is the delegate method, which checks wether to allow user to type the next character or not. so, when the count of the characters in textField goes above 11, keyboard resigns

Comment: this is the delegate method, which checks wether to allow user to type the next character or not. so, when the count of the characters in textField goes above 11, keyboard resigns

Comment: So what should I replace with them when I call the func?

Comment: You won't have to call this function, it is a delegate method for UITextField, You will have to implement the above delegate method and it will automatically check for conditions and do the needful.

Comment: it works, but it has a minor bug after it reaches the limit! after it dismisses the keyboard, it doesn't let me delete the text/character!!

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: thanks for your help, that is perfectly working.

Answer (score -1):

you may try this :

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let count: Int = textField.text?.count ?? 0
    if count >= 11 {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: it won't work, because while the delegate will be called the textField won't contain the total change. This delegate is asking the developer that, will the developer change the previous state of the `UITextField` given the next state.

Comment: But the code that you have written below is very much same as that one I replied with

Comment: check carefully i have not written any answer. As the other answers are same, it simply implies that won't work too, because code don't lies :)

Comment: sorry you have not written that somebody else.
But still what is the problem in this code, it should work as expected, after 10th char as soon as 11th is typed it will hide the keyboard